# php preg_match_all not working

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

Regex is highlighting the wrong words like `Hell«o»` and ignoring the correct words `«Hello»` or `Hello`,
So, my problem is working fine for my javascript code, but when i try it for php it also highlighting the string, which shouldn't:

1. '«This is the point of sale» ';

here is my regex: https://regex101.com/r/SqCR1y/14

PHP Code:

```
$re = '/^(?:.*[[{(«][^\]})»\n]*|[^[{(«\n]*[\]})»].*|.*\w[[{(«].*|.*[\]})»]\w.*)$/m';
$str = '«This is the point of sale»';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

//Output

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(29) "«This is the point of sale»"
  }
}
```

expected: empty array

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kx68nf0r/3/) here, which is working fine

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're not using the right pattern. try this:

```
$re = '/^
  (?:
    \([^)\n] | [^(\n]*\). |
    \[[^]\n] | [^[\n]*\]. |
    {[^}\n] | [^{\n]}.* |
    «[^»\n] | [^«\n]*». |
    .?\w[[{(«]. | .?[\]})»]\w.
  )
$/mxu';
```

Answer (score 0):

What about a string like "(not) balanced)" ?  Should that be legal?

This type of pattern isn't explicit in your test input, but since none of your "good" strings are imbalanced, you could consider covering these cases by using [regex recursion](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html) to match balanced bracket expressions and targeting *valid* strings instead of invalid ones:

```
$re = '/
    ^
    (?!.*\w[{}«»\(\)\[\]]\w)  //disallow brackets inside words
    (?:
    [^\n{}«»\(\)\[\]]|      //non bracket character, OR:
    (                       //(capture group #1, the recursive subpattern) "one of the following balanced groups":
    (\((?:(?>[^\n«»\(\){}\[\]]|(?1))*)\))|  //balanced paren groups
    (\[(?:(?>[^\n«»\(\){}\[\]]|(?1))*)\])|  //balanced bracket groups
    («(?:(?>[^\n«»\(\){}\[\]]|(?1))*)»)|        //balanced chevron groups
    ({(?:(?>[^\n«»\(\){}\[\]]|(?1))*)})     //balanced curly bracket groups
    )
    )+ //repeat "non bracket character or balanced group" until end of string
    $  
/mxu';
```

The recursion takes this form:

```
[openbracket]([nonbracket] | [open/close pattern again via recursion])*[closebracket]
```

To use part of the pattern recursively you identify it via the capture group that encloses it `(?N)`, where N is the number of the group.

*The initial negative lookahead will fail any "word boundary" violations before going into the recursive stuff

*This regex looks to be about 35% faster than the original approach, as seen here: https://regex101.com/r/MBITHe/4